# User/Admin login via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

My page works, in the sense that login will take me to index.php, but it will never re-direct to dashboard.php.  I appreciate any input.

Database columns are: id | username | password | admin
There are only two types of account, the admin account is indicated by a 1

```
<?php

// Get username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// Connect to database
include "db_connect_service.php";

// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$mypassword = crypt($mypassword, '$1$philipphp');

// Query
$result= $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$myusername' AND     password='$mypassword';");

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = $result->rowCount();

// Determine if user is "user" or "admin"
$usertype = $dbh->query("SELECT admin FROM members WHERE username='$myusername';");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($usertype);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1) {

// Start session, register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to login_success.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
$_SESSION['admin'] = $row;

// Redirect to appropriate page depending on user rights. Indicator 0 for user, 1 for admin.
if ($_SESSION['admin'] == 1){
    header("location:dashboard.php");
    }
else {
    header("location:index.php");
    }
$dbh = null;
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$_SESSION['admin'] = $row;` -> you are assign a row. but checking with `1`.

I think your `admin` field is user type in your table. So you have to get user type and compare in `if` condition

Do like this

```
$_SESSION['admin'] = $row["admin"];
```

Comment: This produces the same result.  It just re-routes both a user account, and admin account, to index.php.  Did I miss something?

Comment: did you try with `$row[0]`?

Comment: I did.  Both yielded the same result.

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
$_SESSION['admin'] = $row[0];
```

Comment: Some explanation of how and why this answers the question would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

change that

```
$usertype = $dbh->query("SELECT admin FROM members WHERE username='$myusername';");
```

into

```
$usertype = $dbh->query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username='$myusername' AND admin='1'");

$row = mysql_fetch_row($usertype);
```

did you try `echo` your $row

try to do that like that

because i think you are not getting Value in your `$row` or `$count`